# Fingerprint template matching zkteco

Tags: sql, match, fingerprint, zkteco

I am using zkteco devices for fingerprint registration and verification, and I was wondering if someone can help me of how to match fingerprint templates directly in database like sql db on server side. since I cannot find any way to do it. and the company not responding of giving such mechanism.